# PowerShell - Need to change the installation directory

Tags: powershell, automation

I'm using PowerShell and need to have an installation EXE (not msi) run in silent mode and install into a different directory than the one it defaults to. Instead of "C:\Program Files" I need it to go to "C:\MyTestDirectory", I have tried various arguments and commands but keep failing

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\setup.exe" -ArgumentList '/S /v/qn /D C:\MyTestDirectory'
```

&

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\setup.exe" -ArgumentList '/S /v/qn INSTALLDIR="C:\MyTestDirectory"'
```

Comment: First of all: `Start-Process` does not have a parameter called `-InstallPath`!? ‍♂️ Where did you get this? If the `setup.exe` supports the change of the installation path you should pass it together with the rest of the command line arguments.

Comment: In case you want to instruct the _installer_ what target directory to use, you must use _its command-line options_, and pass them as part of the `-ArgumentList` array - though it's usually better to use a _single_ string. E.g., if your installer uses MSI under the hood and exposes, say, an `INSTALLDIR` property, you could use `-ArgumentList '/S /v /qn INSTALLDIR="C:\MyTestDirectory"'`

Comment: Thank you both, I made adjustments to my comments to reflect my failed attempts.

Comment: @the1fan: `INSTALLDIR` was an _example_ of what a solution might look like. You must consult the documentation of your specific installer (which we know nothing about) to see what the appropriate command-line options are - if supported at all.

Comment: A lot of times you can try to run `setup.exe /?` to get the help.

Comment: Sadly our vendor is requiring us to use an older version of Ghostscript PDF to work with their application. Basic users don't have rights to modify the "C:\Program Files\" directory so they're encountering a driver error. Anyone with elevated privileges doesn't encounter the error. So far none of the cmd line parameters or switches have installed into anything but the "C:\Program Files\" directory. I'll keep testing and post a fix when I find it

Comment: Is the specific version a secret? ‍♂️ ... and you should urgently consider changing your current vendor ... ☝